# How to open the Google Maps App in ios in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, maps, flutter-packages

I'm using the maps_launcher package for Flutter https://pub.dev/packages/maps_launcher, and it's doing it's job when opening apple maps for ios by going directly into the app and not simply displaying a web view page. My function openMap() is also doing the trick for Google Maps in Android, but I can't seem to go directly into the Google Maps app on my real iOS device, which has Google Maps installed and working. It only opens a web view of Google Maps. Any ideas how to make it automatically go to the Google Maps app?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:maps_launcher/maps_launcher.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQueryData(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {



  final myActionSheet = CupertinoActionSheet(
    actions: [
      CupertinoActionSheetAction(
        child: Text('Open in Maps'),
        onPressed: (){
          MapsLauncher.launchCoordinates(
              37.3608503, -122.0581159, '1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA');
        },
      ),
      CupertinoActionSheetAction(
        child: Text('Open in Google Maps'),
        onPressed: (){
          openMap(37.4220041, -122.0862462);
        },
      ),
    ],
  );


  static Future<void> openMap(double latitude, double longitude) async {
    String googleUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$latitude,$longitude';
    if (await canLaunch(googleUrl)) {
      await launch(googleUrl);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not open the map.';
    }
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Maps Launcher Demo',
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: Platform.isIOS ?
                  () {

                    showCupertinoModalPopup(context: context, builder: (context) => myActionSheet);

              } :
                  (){
                openMap(37.4220041, -122.0862462);
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.directions),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package and the following URL schemes:

**comgooglemaps://** and **comgooglemaps-x-callback://** - These schemes allow you to launch the Google Maps app for iOS and perform one of several actions:

- Display a map at a specified location and zoom level.
- Search for locations or places, and display them on a map.
- Request directions from one location to another. Directions can be returned for four modes of transportation: driving, walking, bicycling and public transit.
- Add navigation to your app.
- Through iOS 8, issue a callback when the app has completed, using comgooglemaps-x-callback://. Callbacks are often used to return a user to the app that originally opened Google Maps for iOS. Note that on iOS 9, the system automatically provides a "Back to" link in left corner of the status bar.

Example: `comgooglemaps://?center=$latitude,$longitude&zoom=14`

More info: [ios-urlscheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without `comgooglemaps://` or `comgooglemaps-x-callback://` schemes. Google recommends [universal links](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#universal-cross-platform-syntax).

Use `url_launcher` and you most probably need to define `mode` as `externalApplication`. **Don't forget the mode or it may keep being opened in in-app Safari**.

```
launchUrl(
              // it can be any Google Maps link, no limitations like in the case of comgooglemaps.
              // As long as it works on the web, it will work here.
              Uri.parse("https://maps.app.goo.gl/osFFuRVctqCicwzz6"),
              mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
            )
```